How to vertically position an element within a relative parent
I'm working on a toggle switch, I want to position the toggle knob perfectly vertical within the switch. Here's how I tried to achieve this:
import style from "./Toggle.module.scss";
export default function Toggle() {
    return (
        <>
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" className={style.toggle} />
            <label htmlFor="toggle" className={style.label} />
        </>
    );
}



.toggle {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.label {
    width:60px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius:30px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
    left:10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    
    &::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 23px;
        height: 23px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        background-color: green;
        top: 50%;
        transition: 0.3s;
        
    }
}

.toggle:checked ~ .label::after{
    transform: translateX(32px);

}

I want the ::after property to be absolutely positioned relative to the label. So when i do top 50% I expect this to be perfectly centered.
But it overflows instead, see image:

The question is, why does it work without position relative better than with relative?
I've tried adding relative in combination with
transform: translateY(-50%); 

But then it makes a diagonal movement when clicked :

Try to add "transform: translateY(-50%);" to &::after {}
Edit: Be sure to replace the attributes according to react and css with scss.


.toggle {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.label {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    left: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.label::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    top: 50%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.toggle:checked ~ .label::after {
    transform: translateX(32px) translateY(-50%);
}
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="toggle"/>
<label for="toggle" class=label></label>



